# iOS: Override setter property from superclass in subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I need to override setter of super class in my subclass

SuperClass:

Interface Public:

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) UIView *mediaView;
```

Implementation:

```
 - (void)setMediaView:(UIView *)mediaView
{
 // some code
}
```

SubClass:

Implementation:

```
 - (void)setMediaView:(UIView *)mediaView
{
 // some code
 _mediaView = mediaView; --- ERROR: Use of undeclared identifier '_mediaView'
 // some code 
}
```

How can I fix it? I need to set this property directly

Comment: Show the initializer for the subclass, please.

Comment: @matt, it do not have it

Comment: You need to show more information. Is the property private?

Comment: @matt, its public, sorry forgot to add this point

Answer (score 8):

Solved with code in subclass

```
 @synthesize mediaView = _mediaView;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "super" keyword.

```
- (void)setMediaView:(UIView *)mediaView {
    [super setMediaView:mediaView];
}
```